# Apache fails to start with TLSv1 disabled and does not recognize TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl

I'm having issues trying to disable TLS 1.0 on apache as described here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar  5 2015 18:10:09

$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8

$ openssl version -b -v
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
built on: Mon Apr 27 17:53:56 UTC 2015

$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.27
```

Here are the other SSL related changes I made:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!DH
```

When starting Apache with this in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```

The result is:

```
Syntax error on line 62 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1'
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

When starting Apache with this in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

I have set LogLevel to debug temporarily and here is the log output after when apache fails to start:

```
[Tue May 26 10:02:44 2015] [info] removed PID file /var/run/apache2.pid (pid=17793)
[Tue May 26 10:02:44 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue May 26 10:02:45 2015] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Tue May 26 10:02:45 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:02:45 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:02:45 2015] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
```

When starting Apache with this in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

Starts successfully with this error message:

```
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.22 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.22, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.1
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(253): shmcb_init allocated 524288 bytes of shared memory
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(272): for 524208 bytes (524288 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 136 indexes each
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(306): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(308): subcache_num = 32
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(310): subcache_size = 16376
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(312): subcache_data_offset = 3280
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(314): subcache_data_size = 13096
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(316): index_num = 136
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Shared memory session cache initialised
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.22 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.22, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.1
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [info] Server built: Mar  5 2015 18:10:09
[Tue May 26 10:03:04 2015] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
```

Is the apache documentation incorrect? Is apache somehow using an older version of openssl and thus not accepting the newer protocol flags? What else can I try here?

Comment: TLSv1.1 **(when using OpenSSL 1.0.1 and later)** - from your linked apache manual. What version of openssl do you have?

Comment: My obvious question would be why are you using an out of date build?  You are using a 3 year old build.  There have been numerous security fixes 2012 on the 1.0.1 branch.  I suggest you upgrade to 1.0.1m if nothing else for security reasons.

Comment: @Marki555 - He has the first stable 1.0.1 build from March 2012 its in the very first quote block.

Comment: You might also consider upgrading your version of Apache since it also is several versions behind the current stable build.

Comment: I will look into updating both apache and openssl. However the build date for the openssl version is actually much more recent that that. This is a rackspace managed VPS and I believe they have been updating these older versions with backported security fixes? I will find out for sure.

Comment: @Ramhound it does look like openssl version is reporting a unnspecific version number, i've updated the question with more details

Comment: @Omn - The output of command actually is very specific.  You have 1.0.1 which although was built recently is the intial release ( March 14 2012 ) of the 1.0.1 branch.

Comment: @Ramhound Doesn't the apt-cache policy output indicate the the currently  installed version of openssl is the most recent? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/openssl

Comment: I'll be resolving the version question by contacting Rackspace. Any thoughts on the configuration issue?

Comment: Yes; It does seem like the Ubuntu OpenSSL package is current with all 1.0.1m patches applied; I pointed out my concerns over security only thinking that perhaps your inability to disable TLSv1 was a known issue already fixed.